# How to use 2 versions of MS Excel in windows 10 (version 2007 and Office 365)?

Tags: vb.net, ms-office

I have written a small app with vb.net and my app don't support Office 365, excel (my default Ms.excel) so my app supported ms.excel 2007 version. So my issue is, after I have installed Ms.Excel 2007, when I want to switch to use Ms. office 365, I cannot use switch to use it.
So I really need your helps guys.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. Your question is not about programming  - it's about using different versions of Excel.

Comment: What are you using Excel for?  Is this for reading/writing excel documents, because if so, there are number off third-party tools available to you might be able to use making the office version irrelevant.  OpenXml, ClosedXml, EPPlus are a few examples